# Which files are binaries in a python wheel?

Tags: python, django, python-wheel

[The documentation](https://packaging.python.org/specifications/binary-distribution-format/) says that Python Wheel is a binary distribution format. To understand the difference between the source code and binaries distributed within a Python wheel, I am manually inspecting a `.whl` file from the package `django`. The specific `.whl` I am looking at is [this](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a8/ca/e88eb097959c48cd313dfc4bc394699a48fe5c158ed3a64c13e4fa46c1fd/Django-3.2.9-py3-none-any.whl). I decompressed the wheel file and the top-level directory of the file looks like this:

```
.
├── Django-3.2.9.data
├── Django-3.2.9.dist-info
└── django
```

The `Django-3.2.9.data` file contains a script called `admin.py`. The directory structure for `Django-3.2.9.dist-info` looks like this:

```
.
├── AUTHORS
├── LICENSE
├── LICENSE.python
├── METADATA
├── RECORD
├── WHEEL
├── entry_points.txt
└── top_level.txt
```

The `WHEEL` file in this directory seems to contain information of the WHEEL version that was used to build this `.whl`.

The top-level directory structure for the `django` file looks like this:

```
.
├── __init__.py
├── __main__.py
├── apps
├── bin
├── conf
├── contrib
├── core
├── db
├── dispatch
├── forms
├── http
├── middleware
├── shortcuts.py
├── template
├── templatetags
├── test
├── urls
├── utils
└── views
```

Here, except the `bin` folder, all the other files are source code files that are present on the [django repository](https://github.com/django/django/tree/main/django). Therefore, my guess was that the `bin` folder would contain binaries of the package. However, the folder only contains another python file named `django-admin.py`.

Therefore, my question is:

(1) Does python wheel actually contain a binary? If yes, then how to locate the binary within the `.whl` file?

(2) If the python wheel distributes a binary, then how does wheel distribution ensure that the binary is built from the same source code present in the `.whl` file? For this question, my guess is the source-to-binary integrity is ensured through checksums for each file stored in the `Django-3.2.9.dist-info/RECORD` file. Is that correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Therefore, my guess was that the bin folder would contain binaries of the package.

That's incorrect. Django just happens to have a `bin` directory, since it houses [the `django-admin` command line tool](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/django-admin/).

> Does python wheel actually contain a binary? If yes, then how to locate the binary within the .whl file?

Yes, if there is something that needs to be a compiled binary. For instance, a NumPy wheel would have multiple `.so` (Linux/macOS) or `.pyd` (Windows) files (Python extension modules). Their location within the .whl depends on the package.

You can tell whether a .whl contains binary Pyt .whl does *not* contain binary modules from the name: `Django-3.2.9-py3-none-any.whl`. Compare to e.g. Numpy's `numpy-1.21.4-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl` (containing binary modules for CPython 3.10 on Windows, AMD64 architecture).

If there's other binary package data, such as an image that the package requires, that would be in the .whl too. For Django, you will likely find Gettext `.mo` files.

> If the python wheel distributes a binary, then how does wheel distribution ensure that the binary is built from the same source code present in the .whl file?

Source code for binary modules is just generally not included in .whls.

Comment: I see. Thanks. So django wheel basically contains its python source code (apart from data files, such as .mo files), and does not need to have the python code to be built into binaries (for different architectures), is that correct?

Comment: Follow-up question: Why is the wheel called a `binary` distribution format then?

Comment: It's a format that *can* distribute binaries, but it isn't *required* to do so. The file itself is just a ZIP archive; the important part is that it has a defined format that means tools that process wheel files know to treat the files found inside.

Comment: (a) Yes, that's correct. Django doesn't contain any extension modules. (b) Because unlike .tar.gz files, wheels _can_ contain extension modules and are equipped to deal with the different architectures, etc.